# Why time complexity is constant, though iteration between a big number?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

if we iterate through 0 to 100000 then time complexity is O(1)

```
for _ in range (0,100000):
```

but if a array contains only 5 element & we iterate through the array then it will be O(n).
why???

```
for n in range(len(arr)):
```

Comment: Time complexity is not a property of an actual program. It is a property of an algorithm with an input of potentially unbounded size. It doesn't make any sense to talk about time complexity of a program without specifying what we are supposed to interpret as that input.

Comment: In your code `n` is not an input to the program, so it doesn't make sense to talk about the complexity as a function of `n`.